# Resizing pictures in Photoshop CC 2017

Tags: printing, adobe-photoshop

Is there a difference in quality when resizing a picture using the Transform tool rather than using the IMAGE > IMAGE SIZE method?  I already convert image to smart object and use the bicubic reduction option.  I'm trying to avoid an extra copy when reducing pictures to put on a gang sheet for printing multiple pictures at once.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Image Size dialog you have more options to minimize the loss of quality that occurs when resizing an image, including the option to preserve details and reduce noise at the same time.

To resize a group of images to the same size, you can record an action while resizing the first image and then apply the action to the other images.

To fit multiple images on a sheet you can use the Contact Sheet automation.

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/resizing-image.html

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/create-contact-sheets.html